# 2.4GHz extension for RC

Tags: soldering, remote-control, pcb-antenna

I’m very new to this field.

We just purchased a ride-on car for our toddler.  Everything works well but the distance between remote and car is limited to approx 30 ft, which we were hoping to extend.

Please help me identify where one would solder on a 2.4GHz antenna to this PCB or if it’s even possible and thanks in advance!

[image: Front side of board]

[image: Back side of board]

Comment: Not possible, not legal and not likely.

Comment: Stick a vertical wire a bit more than twice the length of the antenna line from the dot in the corner on Rx, then  Tx same. You might get a bit more range or less.

Comment: Why would you want your toddler to be more than 30 feet away from you on a motorized platform? I expect there are safety reasons why this is a very bad idea.

Comment: Elliot, this and most ride-on toddler cars are also controlled by an I/O gas peddle and steering wheel on the car.  I would like to be able to stop him if he drives out of range.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to change the transmitter, it will alter its characteristics and mess up communications on other bands. Making this change is also illegal in the USA and many other countries. However you can extend the receiving range by modifying the receiving antenna. You can modify it in any way you want, make it longer, shorter etc. You can experiment and see what works the best for you.

Comment: Thanks Gil!  Would a directional antenna be an option?  I will crank open the receiver and add around the chassis of the vehicle, hopefully that could help on that end :)

Comment: The directional antenna would be the best option however it will affect the location direction from the transmitter. Thanks for keeping us up-to-date.